# Finding the distance travelled by a fly in a room from one lower corner to the diagonally opposite one

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, distance

> A room has a length of 4 meters, width of 5 meters and height of 3
> meters. A fly is on one of the corners and walks to the diagonally
> opposite one. What is the length of the shortest possible traveled path?

[image]

The path of the fly is in red.

I did:

$$d = k + 3$$

where k is the floor diagonal, and

$$k^2 = 4^2+5^2 \Leftrightarrow k = \sqrt{41}$$

So $d = \sqrt{41} + 3 \approx 9.4$. The solutions say it should be 8.6 meters. Where did it go wrong? Also how do you know that the red path is the shortest path possible without testing all the alternatives? This is a simple problem so it is "obvious" that it is but what if this were a more complicated one?

Comment: This is a geometry problem, not a physics problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k = sqrt (4^2 + 5^2) = 6.4

Why didn't the fly fly instead? Would have shorter & quicker.
corner-corner diagonal = sqrt k^2 + 3^2 = sqrt (6.4^2 + 3^2) = 7.07

Your math looks correct for 9.4, the face diagonal +3.

Comment: The fly does fly in a different exercise, and that's the answer too. Thanks

Comment: I like the answer below, with the box all folded out flat to make a cross-like shape.The fly walks quasi-diagonally across the end face, then quasi-diagonally across the bottom face.  Distance = sqrt ( (3+4)^2 + 5^2) = 8.6

Answer (score 2):

That is not the shortest path. To see the shortest path imagine you flatten the room as if you unfold a cardboard box, draw a straight line between the two points, and rebuild the box. See [here](http://www.smallperturbation.com/two-ants) for a lengthier explanation. The answer will be $k^2=(4+3)^2+5^2$, thus $k=8.6$